# \maketitle Undefined control sequence on overleaf

Tags: titles, undefined, control, sequence

I'm have a problem with \maketitle on overleaf, the code works fine and produces the required output, but stil a error and i wanna find out why does it happen.

So the problem is:

[image]

Thats the latex code: (the error is on \maketitle)

```
\documentclass[
    article,        
    11pt,           
    oneside,        
    a4paper,            
    brazil,     
    brazil,         
    sumario=tradicional
    ]{abntex2}


\usepackage{lmodern}            
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage{indentfirst}        
\usepackage{nomencl}            
\usepackage{color}              
\usepackage{graphicx}           
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{microtype}          
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newsavebox\foobox
\newlength{\foodim}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][0]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \foodim=#1\wd\foobox
        \hskip \wd\foobox
        \hskip -0.5\foodim
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
        \hskip 0.5\foodim
}}
\def\Laplace{\slantbox[-.45]{$\mathscr{L}$}}


\usepackage{lipsum} 

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{bibli.bib} 

\title{Desenvolvimento de um sistema}
\autor{Ana M Brito}
\local{Brasil}
\data{Setembro de 2021}

\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{41,5,195}

\makeatletter

\makeatother

\setlrmarginsandblock{3cm}{3cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{3cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\setlength{\parindent}{1.3cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm} 

\SingleSpacing
\begin{document}
\frenchspacing 

\maketitle % error here

\begin{resumoumacoluna}

Resumo aqui

\vspace{\onelineskip}

\end{resumoumacoluna}

\textual

\section{Introdução}

introducao

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If I add `\tituloestrangeiro{some title}` the errors goes away, but as I can't read portugues (and so can't read the documentation of you class) I don't know if that is the best solution.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This really has nothing to do with Overleaf, so I'm removing that tag.  The components of `\maketitle` are defined by the document class; the class you are using is Portuguese, so it's not so surprising that `\title` has been replaced by its Portuguese equivalent.  This might be true for `\author` as well, so it would be a good idea to read the documentation.

Comment: So i should read the documentation for a specific component? would be the document "\documentclass - Portuguese"?

Comment: There are three files that should be useful here; all are part of the package on CTAN: https://ctan.org/pkg/abntex2 (1) The main package documentation is linked from that page. (2) The "article template" is in the `doc/examples` subdirectory of the package, in two parts: the pdf file (which doesn't have complete instructions for the commands to be used) and (3) the source, `abntex2-modelo-artigo.tex`, which produces the pdf file.  By comparing (2) and (3) you should be able to find how to input the pieces that are used by `\maketitle`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer your solution works! I belive is because the template i'm using its based in ABNT, (brazilian association of tecnical rules) and the whole code must follow the rules. I appreciate all help from all. Thank all very much.